# scp permission denied for single file

Tags: rhel, scp

From my windows machine I would like to scp (I have git bash installed) 2 files to a directory on a redhat box.

In the directory where the 2 files are I do in my terminal

```
user@workstation$ scp file1.jar user@remote:/home/user/dir/ FAILS: permission denied
user@workstation$ scp file2.jar user@remote:/home/user/dir/ WORKS
```

Surprisingly, both files (locally) have the same permissions (`ls -al`)

```
-rw-r--r--    1 user   admin 58706904 Jun  4 16:02 file1.jar
-rw-r--r--    1 user   admin 45033480 Jun  4 16:02 file2.jar
```

On the remote server I gave the target directory `dir` full permissions to everyone (`chmod 777`)

```
drwxrwxrwx  3 user root       4096 Jun  4 16:16 .
```

Neither on the windows nor on the redhat machine I have admin access.

Thanks for the help

Comment: What are the permissions of the remote version of file1.jar?

Comment: remote version of file1.jar? I have file1.jar locally

Comment: Is there a remote one that’s not letting you overwrite it?

Comment: no I deleted file1.jar on remote (it used to work)

Comment: This is somewhat old now, but it would have been good to see the actual error message and the transcript of running `scp` with `-v` (verbose) option.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of copying the two files `file1.jar`, `file2.jar` from the directory where they were created (by packaging a maven project using `mvn clean package` in the java project folder) to a separate folder before sending them with `scp` to the remote server, I sent them from the original directory directly and that worked.

So copying the files must have done something to the permissions of one of the files but not to the other. Really strange. But anyways, it works now..